# Positioning an object over an image in HTML + CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, css-position

I'm making a spot-the-difference game in HTML, CSS + Javascript, but one of the problems I'm facing is that on a different resolution, the marker circles & hitboxes (basically just an image that links to a javascript function which fades in the marker circle) are all in the wrong places.

I'm using absolute positioning in CSS with percentage values. The main image that the markers and hitboxes get overlaid on is 50% width and height of the page.

Thanks,

Niall.

Edit: added info about the main image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Your edit:

> The main image that the markers and hitboxes get overlaid on is 50% width and height of the page.

...substantially changes the question. :-) My answer below about using pixel values for the overlays remains valid; but calculating their positions becomes a nightmare because you can't know at design time what the actual width of the image will be. This means you have to find out what the *actual* width/height of the image is at runtime (e.g., via JavaScript) and then adjust the pixel values you use for absolutely positioning everything else to account for that.

If you can avoid it (for instance, by just offering a few standard sizes), I'd recommend avoiding it. If you can't, I'd recommend using a library (like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries)) for discovering the actual computed width and height of the image.

---

**Original answer**:

> I'm using absolute positioning in CSS with percentage values.

That would be the problem, then. If you want to accurately place something on top of an image, as the pixels in the image will be fixed, you'll want to use pixel values rather than percentages, like this ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ifana4/2)):

**CSS**:

```
#main {
  /* Ensure that #main is an offset container */
  position: relative;
}
#main img {
  /* Position the image at 0,0 */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
#main div {
  /* Position the div at 16,16 (middle of the 32x32 image */
  position: absolute;
  left: 16px;
  top: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <p>Positioning example:</p>
  <div id='main'>
    <img src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2f37f49d08a02f40fe0c86529969c47a?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG'>
    <div>This starts half-way into and half-way down your gravatar</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is I have the main image set as 50% height & width. I'll edit my question now.

Comment: Ok, sorry for not making it clear at the start :) I'll just offer 2 standard sized images (one for 4:3 screens and one for 16:9 & 16:10) and calculate positions based on that. Thanks :)